# Two flex ducts connected to metal trunk duct?

Tags: ducts, trailer

Trailer from the 70th.
Metal square trunk duct ( 58') runs underneath, no branches.
There were two flex ducts connected to the trunk duct, to the left and right of AC unit. Connected with a splitter to the AC.. ( one 8" flex duct coming from the ac unit going into the splitter coming out as two 6" flex ducts going into the trunk)

Do I really need the two flex ducts? Why can't I just connect one flex duct to the trunk?( Both removed flex ducts are removed now)

Comment: Why the question if you have already removed them?

Comment: How about a picture of what was there? Did the flex come from the AC unit then feed into the metal trunk? Was there any other feed from the AC unit to the trunk? Maybe this is how they got the cold air into the trunk, and now that the flex is gone your AC will just be pumping into the great outdoors...

Comment: 70th? Did you mean 70s?

Comment: Rohit- I need to hook up the unit back to the trunk. I wasn't sure if I need two flex ducts - now I know I should use two

Answer (score 0):

My wild guess is that the trunk duct isn't large enough to support connection of an 8" branch duct. Therefore, the 8" duct was split for more convenient attachment to the trunk.

Regardless, you can probably change that configuration if you maintain adequate cross-sectional area of the duct(s) so you don't reduce flow efficiency.

```
Area = πr^2 (circle)

     = 3.14 x 4^2"
     = 50.3 square inches for an 8" duct

     = 3.14 x 3^2" x 2
     = 56.6 square inches for two 6" ducts
```

For rectangular ducts just multiply width by height.